# Video Library for Processing Android

Tags: android, video, processing

I need a video library for "Processing Android" to play some videos in my game. I tried ApWidget VideoView but it works only when a video file is placed on sd card and its path is provided to video view object. But how can i play videos that are placed in data folder of my sketch?

Answer (score 0):

My experience is assets such as videos or images have to be in the Assets folder in your app tree (I'm assuming you use Eclipse). Otherwise your assets won't export when you compile the app.
If there's an issue with the code, we need to see it to answer further. Best of luck!

Comment: No, I am not using Eclipse. I am using "Processing 2.x/3.x" and for Processing, all assets are placed inside data folder of the sketch.